# Pontryagin maximum principle and constraints

Tags: constraints

I have studied the Pontryagin Maximum Principle. It is about solving a problem like this:
$$
\begin{cases}
\min \int_{t_0}^{t_1} f(t,x,u) dt\\
x(t_0) = x_0\\
\dot x = g(t,x,u)\\
u \in U
\end{cases}
$$

where $U$ is the set of admissible control. We have to find $u$ and $x$.

I am trying to link this theorem to a different problem, that is to find the min/max of the function $f(x_1, x_2) = x_1 x_2$ constrained to $g(x_1, x_2) = x_1^2+x_2^2 -1 = 0$.
I used to solve this problem with Lagrange multipliers but now I'm wondering how can I use Pontryagin principle.
For instance, in this last case, I noted that $f$ does not depend on $t$.
Which is the functional I have to minimize?